# Changing for loop to while loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

This is the for loop that I need to convert to a while loop. I thought this would work, but it is giving me an error of no attribute for move. This is a program that creates a graphics image of a face, so all 'shapes' in 'shapeList' are the head, nose, mouth, eyes. The face needs to move along the edges of the window.

```
def moveAll(shapeList, dx, dy):
    for shape in shapeList: 
        shape.move(dx, dy)    


def moveAll(shapeList, dx, dy): 
    shape = []
    while shape != shapeList:
        shapeList.append(shape)
        shape.move(dx, dy)
```

Comment: What are the inputs and the expected outputs?

Comment: The `for` loop looks correct. Why change it?

Comment: The for loop is correct. The assignment is to switch it to a while loop and I am stuck with attribute error.

Comment: Well, `shapeList.append(shape)` is just appending `shape`, which is always `[]` , to `shapeList`, and you are calling `move(dx,dy)` on an empty list (namely, `[]`). That's why you got that error.

Comment: What you should do is to repeatedly get an element out of `shapeList`, and call `move(dx,dy)` , until you've visited every element in `shapeList`.

Answer (score 0):

In the `while` loop version of your code, the `shape` variable is initialized as a list, so it naturally does not have a `move` method. To convert your `for` loop into a `while` loop that's basically about iterating over a list of shape objects, you can convert the list to a `collections.deque` object so that you can efficiently dequeue a queue of shape objects until it's empty:

```
from collections import deque
def moveAll(shapeList, dx, dy):
    queue = deque(shapeList)
    while queue:
        shape = queue.popleft()
        shape.move(dx, dy)
```

Comment: This works well, I do think there is another way, but thank you for this.

Answer (score 0):

weird question, weird answer hehe

```
def moveAll(shapeList, dx, dy): 
    try:
        ilist = iter(shapeList)
        while True:
            shape = next(ilist)
            shape.move(dx, dy)
    except:
        pass # done
```

Comment: This will fail if `move` returns anything other than a trueish value (e.g. `None` which would be somewhat likely).

Comment: you are right haha. any idea on how to handle that?

Comment: You will have to store the result of `next()` separately, and then call `move` on it. You’ll likely need a `while True` loop for that.

Comment: ah! ok.........

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
def moveAll(shapeList, dx, dy):
    while shapeList:
        shape = shapeList.pop(0)
        shape.move(dx, dy)
```

As long as the list has items, we remove one and process it.

The `for` loop is probably both more efficient and more idiomatic, though.

Comment: Note that this mutates the incoming list, which might not be what one would expect here (OP’s for loop does not mutate it).

Comment: True; a simple workaround is to copy `shapeList[:]` to another variable and then `pop` from that instead.